# How can I work with data that I get from SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to work with data that I get from a SQL Server database directly in my ASP.NET code behind page. I have the connection string, should I use `DataSet` for accessing the data?

I want to work and customize data and then show it on an ASP.NET page in XML format (use it for xmlhttprequest answer).

Sample code would be greatly appreciated!

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=user_city;Integrated Security=True");
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand my_command = new SqlCommand("select * from city_buildings where user_id=1",con);
```

Comment: I think first you should buy a book and read about asp.net you are asking a totally basic question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is many choices to get data from database. You wrote some code to directly retrieve data from database. You can see complete sample from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

There is also other methods: Entity Framework, NHibernate and etc.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [Entity Framework Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials).

---

The ADO.NET Entity Framework supports data-centric applications and services, and provides a platform for programming against data that raises the level of abstraction from the logical relational level to the conceptual level. By enabling developers to work with data at a greater level of abstraction, the Entity Framework supports code that is independent of any particular data storage engine or relational schema.

---

References:

[The ADO.NET Entity Framework Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)